# Preg Replace text based on string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i am trying to figure out why this has no result.

I am fetching data from wp database

```
        $global_notice2 = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_global_notice', true);
```

This contains an a href link i wish to manipulate using preg replace before displaying it for the user such as

```
        preg_replace('/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>/', '', $global_notice2 );
```

Now we display the data

```
$notice2 = "<p>$alternative_content$global_notice2</p>";
```

The data is unmodified, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you assign the new value to a variable?

Comment: whopsie... been a long day. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace` don't modify the argument, you need to catch the return like this :

```
$global_notice2 = preg_replace('/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>/', '', $global_notice2);
```

See [preg_replace documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)